# dificuldade ao instalar pathtrackr no r pelo github

Tags: r, github, packages

Estou tentando instalar o pacote pathtrackr, esperava que ao executar o código  `install_github("aharmer/pathtrackr", build_vignettes = TRUE)` o pacote fosse instalado, entretanto ao executar o código a mensagem de output é:

```
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

 1: All                                
 2: CRAN packages only                 
 3: None                               
 4: Rcpp      (1.0.3  -> 1.0.4 ) [CRAN]
 5: testthat  (2.3.0  -> 2.3.2 ) [CRAN]
 6: digest    (0.6.22 -> 0.6.25) [CRAN]
 7: rlang     (0.4.1  -> 0.4.5 ) [CRAN]
 8: glue      (1.3.1  -> 1.4.0 ) [CRAN]
 9: backports (1.1.5  -> 1.1.6 ) [CRAN]
10: processx  (3.4.1  -> 3.4.2 ) [CRAN]
11: ps        (1.3.0  -> 1.3.2 ) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates:

Downloading GitHub repo aoles/EBImage@master
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                                   
2: CRAN packages only                    
3: None                                  
4: BiocGenerics (0.30.0 -> 0.32.0) [CRAN]
5: digest       (0.6.22 -> 0.6.25) [CRAN]
6: Rcpp         (1.0.3  -> 1.0.4 ) [CRAN]
7: rlang        (0.4.1  -> 0.4.5 ) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates:

√  checking for file 'C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpauObSg\remotes2c3046934f4\aoles-EBImage-e750cd7/DESCRIPTION' (4.1s)
-  preparing 'EBImage': (1.2s)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  installing the package to build vignettes (763ms)
E  creating vignettes (52.3s)
   --- re-building 'EBImage-introduction.Rmd' using rmarkdown
   Error: processing vignette 'EBImage-introduction.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
   there is no package called 'BiocStyle'
   --- failed re-building 'EBImage-introduction.Rmd'

   SUMMARY: processing the following file failed:
     'EBImage-introduction.Rmd'

   Erro: Vignette re-building failed.
   Execução interrompida
Erro: Failed to install 'pathtrackr' from GitHub:
  Failed to install 'EBImage' from GitHub:
  System command error, exit status: 1, stdout + stderr (last 10 lines):
E> --- re-building 'EBImage-introduction.Rmd' using rmarkdown
E> Error: processing vignette 'EBImage-introduction.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
E> there is no package called 'BiocStyle'
E> --- failed re-building 'EBImage-introduction.Rmd'
E> 
E> SUMMARY: processing the following file failed:
E>   'EBImage-introduction.Rmd'
E> 
E> Erro: Vignette re-building failed.
E> Execução interrompida
>
```

Tenho limitados conhecimentos de programação e se puderem me ajudar com guias de leitura ou tutoriais serei grato, meu sistema operacional é windows 10 home. Ja tentei atualizar o devtools e baixar separadamente o ebimage, mas nada funciona.

Comment: Olá, está usando RStudio?

Comment: O pacote em falta, `'BiocStyle'` é um pacote `Bioconductor`. Veja [aqui](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/BiocStyle.html) como instalá-lo. Depois tente outra vez instalar esse pacote do GitHub.

Comment: Olá obrigado e me desculpe pela demora.
Faço uso do RStudio e fiz o download do 'BiocStyle'.

Comment: Baixei separadamente o EBImage, entretanto o proximo erro encontrado foi:
`Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
  (convertido do aviso) cannot open file 'C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-reshape2/00new/reshape2/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'reshape2'
* removing 'C:/Users/Usuário/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/reshape2'
Erro: Failed to install 'pathtrackr' from GitHub:
  (convertido do aviso) installation of package ‘reshape2’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: Consegui instalar ao definir o diretório específico `install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("aharmer/pathtrackr", lib="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library")`

Comment: @AugustoGonçalves Que bom que conseguiu resolver seu problema. Agora poste a solução como resposta aqui neste tópico e depois marque como "resposta aceita". Assim vai ajudar outras pessoas que estão com o mesmo problema.